# Format currency with textField

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `textField` which lets the user enter money. I don't want to only support the American dollar sign $. I want it to support all currency's. But the problem is, some dollar symbols are after the money (such as German: 27.99€).

So the money symbol has to appear even before the user enters an amount. With Americans dollar symbol, it's easy, just do `$  .` But with others, such as €, I don't see how I can do it.

My question is, how can I display the money symbol so it fit's the current currency?

Also, if the user changes currency's, do the saved amounts of money also change automatically, or would I have to change it manually?

**Update**

I tried the following:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[currencyFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[currencyFormatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
```

How can I make that appear in the `textField`?

Comment: show how you're storing the values and what code you've tried so far (and what it does wrong)

Comment: I store the values in SQLite with just the number, not the money sign. I checked up a couple of the similar questions on stackoverflow, but I don't think they addressed both my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has very good support for localization.

You want to use a combination of locales and NSNumberFormatters. If you create a number formatter, configure it for currency and set the locale to Germany it should display the currency value correctly (currency symbol at the end, a comma as the decimal separator, etc.)

This code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *theGermanLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier: @"de_DE"];
currencyFormatter.locale = theGermanLocale;
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

double value = 12.34;
NSString *germanCurrencyString = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber: @(value)];
NSLog(@"%f in German currency is \"%@\"", value, germanCurrencyString)
```

Displays:

> 12.34 in German currency is "12,34 €"

There is no need to set the number of digits, or to require a decimal separator. Setting the formatter to `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` configures all the settings in the number formatter correctly for the specified locale. That's the whole point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I updated the question with the code. How can I insert that in the textFIeld?

Comment: Oh come on now! Take a look at the docs for NSNumberFormatter. Is there a method that takes a number as input and returns a string as output?

Comment: Hint: It's covered in the section of the Xcode docs titled "Converting Between Numbers and Strings", and it has both "string" and "number" in its name. And to install a string into a text field, you set it's text property.

Comment: What I meant was: how can I make it by default to show the following: "`$  .  `"  (or which ever is the default currency) then let the user enter the amount

Comment: That's what I mean as well. If you set the locale of a number formatter to "de_DE" (German for Germany) and use the code `NSString *displayString = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber: @"12.34"]` Then what you get back is `12,34 €`. Try it. It works.

Comment: The number formatter sets up the decimal separator, currency symbol, placement of the currency symbol in the output string, etc, all for you.

Comment: I think @Eric is wanting to have a textfield that auto formats the currency value as the user types - which is a fairly complex task when you consider invalid input, copy/paste, cursor placement, etc.